# Build a UI builder for Front-End (Drag Drop with code split)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, reactjs, web-component, web-frontend

I am looking to do a research/develop to make a UI editor (like WYSIWYG). There should be a control panel for components (like buttons,labels..etc) and be dragging them into a panel area it should generate the UI and corresponding code.

If anyone can give me a hint it is very helpful.

Thank you All

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a repository of components. After that make a factory that will return the specific component. Then create an UI for components lists, so that user can pick a component from that list and drag it to his page/screen. You must also make a property window for the component so the user can give the height/width, styling and other feature to that component. property window may be specific to the component.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea

Comment: Are there frameworks ? which we can build these types of scenarios

Comment: So you are asking for the framework. So can get react-quill or alloy-editor

Comment: Thank you and are you on twitter?